# Set value in form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've a HTML form which has an input..I want to take data from my form and set the other data of the form based on this input

for eg

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="text1" name="t1"> 
    <input type="text" id="text2" name="t2">
    <button type="button" >Find  </button>
 </form>
```

So how to set value in text2 based on text1 on clicking the button using php, javascript and ajax?

I've a text-box from which i will obtain a value (ie text1)
now I want to pass this value to a database and retrive information from the database (based on text 1) and set the value of text2 to the retrived information.

I've tried sending an ajax request to the same file, but it did not work, when I sent an ajax request to a another file I wasn't able to make a script

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: what have you attempted so far, anything besides the html?

Comment: added some discription

Comment: Why do you think you need an AJAX request? AJAX is for getting data from the server, you just want to use the data in the form.

Comment: ok so how do i pass data from form to php to get data from a database?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to take data from my form and set the other data of the form
>   based on this input

Here's the solution using Javascript:

```
function func(){
    var val = document.getElementById('text1').value
    document.getElementById('text2').value= val
}
```

where func() is a function that is called on click of button

```
<button type="button" onclick="func()"> Find  </button>
```

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uo74uz3f/)